# android.os.Parcel.createException Too many receivers, total of 1000,

Tags: android, google-play-services

Fabrics Issue. Not able to catch where it is coming from.Can anybody explain why it is occuring? I guess the issue is related to google api client.

```
  Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many receivers, total of 1000, registered for pid: 14270
      at android.os.Parcel.createException + 1974(Parcel.java:1974)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1934(Parcel.java:1934)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1884(Parcel.java:1884)
      at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiver + 3690(IActivityManager.java:3690)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal + 1567(ContextImpl.java:1567)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver + 1528(ContextImpl.java:1528)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver + 1516(ContextImpl.java:1516)
      at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver + 636(ContextWrapper.java:636)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zaa + 64(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:64)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.zab + 311(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:311)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaf.onConnectionSuspended + 42(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:42)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.onConnectionSuspended + 106(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:106)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zap.onConnectionSuspended + 9(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:9)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaf.onConnectionSuspended + 4(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage + 40(:40)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zze.dispatchMessage + 8(:8)
      at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7050(ActivityThread.java:7050)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 964(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Comment: Try searching `registerReceiver()` method usage in your code. A possible issue is that you register receiver and don't unregister it when it's not needed (usually register/unregister should be tied to lifecycle).

Comment: I got same Exception Also looking for cause.

Comment: Hi Aditya, any chance you have an update on this?

Comment: Hi Aditya, Did you find a fix? I too have the same type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing and found out that at some point I called `sendBroadcast(SOME_ACTION)` from within a `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered to `SOME_ACTION`.

Things will seem OK for a while, but since it is all running on the same thread the receivers will actually hang around until the maximum number is reached. Don't be fooled by the calls to registerReceiver in the stack trace, that's just how the calls are routed.